# What is affected by the EMP killstreak?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

When an EMP is activated, what killstreak rewards are destroyed if they're in-progress?  Are there any that are immune (that "finish up")?

What about deployable items?

Answer (score 3):

The EMP functions the similarly to how it did in Modern Warfare 2. The only killstreak rewards not affected by it appear to be Emergency Airdrops if they are deployed at the time of the EMP. Since the M.O.A.B. has an EMP effect, another EMP can't be deployed to destroy it.

As for deployables: Claymores are destroyed, and C4 detonation doesn't work.

[Source](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/EMP).

Answer (score 3):

The EMP will destroy almost all killstreak rewards, *including* the stealth bomber if it has just started flying overhead, *and* if you have an Escort Airdrop Osprey inbound, it will destroy that too.

Things it will destroy:

- UAV or Counter UAV
- IMS (and Claymores/Bouncing Betties)
- Predator missile (although catching it in flight is very tricky)
- All turrets (sentry/remote sentry/SAM)
- All helicopters
- Any bombing runs, if the bombs have not yet fired
- Care package delivery vehicles (the chopper or the Osprey, including the Juggernaut delivery chopper, although it's *fast*)
- AC-130
- Reaper drone

I believe the MOAB is immune, and its EMP effect means that you won't be able to call in your own EMP while it's going off anyhow.

It can be very useful to set your highest Support package killstreak to the EMP, as by the late game the enemy team is likely to have a number of high-order killstreaks, and you can destroy them immediately with the EMP, regardless of how difficult they are to shoot down.

The other benefit of the EMP is that it will keep enemy killstreaks offline for an entire minute after it is used.  You can use this close to the end of a round to keep any "power players" on the enemy team from calling in their killstreaks.

It also effects equipment your enemies carry, such as the heartbeat sensor and certain types of sights, and it kills your radar and much of your HUD.  These effects can be avoided if you use Assassin Pro, however.

In my opinion, the EMP in previous games was pretty worthless compared to other high order killstreaks, but the introduction of the Support strike package (and its kill count that does not reset) in this game means that it is far more useful than it was previously.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that the ENTIRE enemy team has laid out, aerial or ground based killstreaks or equipment is destroyed and no more killstreaks can be called in for one minute. Some enemy killstreaks can only be destroyed by an EMP, those being the Stealth Bomber and Precision Airstrike. The EMP does not counter an enemy MOAB if the MOAB has already been called in by the time of EMP detonation. In other words, the EMP can only prevent a MOAB, not stop it. Agent 86 is also correct on that point, Unless you have Assassin Pro (the regular Assassin perk doesn't protect against the effect of an EMP) all of your HUD is disabled and any electronic attachments to your guns and your launchers are disabled for that minute. No killstreaks will get the chance to finish up because they will be destroyed immediately. You can deploy a portable radar with Assassin Pro equipped while an enemy EMP is active as a substitute for UAV support until the minute is up, it will work. Even with Assassin Pro equipped, the Javelins ground lock on will still be disabled for that time as well.